# Как редактировать BMP-файл в Python?

Tags: python, файлы, bmp

У меня задача - открыть с бинарном режиме BMP-файл и изменить его (сделать негатив данной картинки). По условию:

> На вход программе подается BMP-файл, содержащий некоторое изображение.
> Без использования сторонних графических библиотек (например, PIL)
> сформируйте новый файл, в который сохраните негатив, полученный из
> исходного изображения.
>
> У BMP-файла очень простая структура. Первые 54 байта являются
> заголовком, и их нужно оставить без изменения. А все остальные байты
> надо заменить на значение, вычисленное как 255-value, где value - это
> значение прочитанного байта.

Однако, если открыть файл, то откроются 2 блока: один на 104 байт, остальной - оставшееся кол-во байт.

```
f = open('3214.bmp', mode='rb')
```

Даже если это как-то умудриться обработать и попытаться записать в конечный файл эти данные - выходит ошибка.

```
with open('312312.bmp', 'wb') as f1:
    f1.write(bytes(z))
    f1.write(bytes(t))
```

Тут z - список int значений первых 54 байт, t - все остальные

> f1.write(bytes(t))
> TypeError: 'bytes' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Как все-таки необходимо реализовать такую обработку файла? Ибо у меня просто кончились идеи, как я могу выполнить задачу.

Comment: Приведите [mcve], по этим обрывкам не получится понять что происходит

Comment: А функция `bytes()` принимает одно из трёх значений — или число (длину), или байты, или коллекцию чисел в диапазоне 0-255. Текст ошибки намекает, что ваше `t` не является ни одним из этих разрешённых значений

Answer (score 8, accepted):

не смотря не то, что "ванильный" способ малоэффективен и ресурсоемок, сделать это можно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
f = open('butterfly.bmp', mode='rb')
header = f.read(54)
res = [255-val for val in f.read()]
f.close()
o = open("neg.bmp", mode="wb")
o.write(header)
o.write(bytes(res))
o.close()
```

Или, используя контекст-менеджеры (что правильнее):

```
with open('butterfly.bmp', mode='rb') as inputfile:
    header = inputfile.read(54)
    res = [255-val for val in inputfile.read()]
    with  open("neg.bmp", mode="wb") as outputfile:
        outputfile.write(header)
        outputfile.write(bytes(res))
```

Получим, соответственно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Лучше всё-таки использовать контексты, чем надеяться, что всё будет хорошо и дело дойдёт до close)

Comment: @vp_arth справедливо.

Comment: Видимо, я не до конца разобрался в теме файлов, раз не додумался, что все так просто. Большое спасибо за помощь!